# In Night in the Woods (2017), Why is your third jump in a row always higher?

Tags: night-in-the-woods

During gameplay in Night in the Woods (2017), if you hold the left\right direction control and press the jump button three times in quick successions you will do two low jumps and then a high jump.

Has this gameplay mechanic been confirmed to serve a purpose during a playthrough, such as being necessary during a particular section, and has the creator ever addressed it?

Answer (score 1):

The same feature is present in almost all Mario games simply called the triple jump. It is an intentional feature meant to give you an advantage by stringing together combos of jumps. It does have a necessity through-out the run such as jumping between the pirate ship in a later area and can also be used to reach certain areas you would not normally be able to such as the power lines

Comment: Does this answer address the question? It seems like it would be better as a comment.

Comment: That makes sense in a platform game like Mario, but Night in the Woods is more of a narrative adventure, so I wasn't expecting to see it there. I guess it might simply be baked into the engine.

Comment: Isn't the pirate ship part of the prologue as opposed to part of a later area? I also believe triple jump isn't necessary to get up to the power lines for the most part, you usually either get up by jumping off of something then up to the power lines or drop onto them from a rooftop